# MVC3, Where is the request coming from

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

Trying to figure out the best way to get the web page the user is coming from in MVC3.

I am building a download file function and if the user hasn't been linked to the file from my own website I want to redirect them to a page of my choosing.

I basically want to stop people from directly linking to my files without passing through my web site first.

How would i do this in the most reliable way?

Comment: Do you want the user to only access the file after logged in?

Comment: No, users will never be logged in. I only want to make sure they have gotten to the file from a link on my web site. If the link to the file is comming from an external website that is linking to my file I want to redirect them to another page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The super simple way (that would work most of the time), would be to take a look at `Request.UrlReferrer` in your controller. That should contain the URL the visitor came from.

Answer (score 1):

MVC3 still has ASP.NET as base. So you can use all of the features of ASP.NET too...

Another way is to use an IIS-Extension => https://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&g=6&i=1288 (LeechGuard from Microsoft)

Comment: Thanks, ill look into that. 
I would however, if possible, not involve any external dependencies.

Comment: You also can look into the shipped AccountController - the LogOn method is using Url.IsLocalUrl(<url>)

Answer (score 0):

This is how I've solved it for now.
If a request for a file comes in the page to show info about the file is displayed. To download the file the user clicks a link pointing to the same page.

When the code detects that the user is requesting a file from the files own URL the file is served to the user.

```
    private bool RequestIsCommingFromSamePage()
    {
        if (Request.UrlReferrer == null)
            return false;

        string requestURL = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
        string pageURL = Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"] + Request.RawUrl;

        requestURL = requestURL.Replace("http://", "").Replace("https://", "");

        if (requestURL == pageURL || pageURL == null || requestURL == null)
            return true;

        return false;
    }
```